# How to delete rows checked as false from datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am new to c#. I am trying to import some data from excel sheet and then i displayed it in datagridview like this

```
  OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select email from [" + loadtextfeild.Text + "$] where email like '%@%'     ", conn);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
  Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(opentextfeild.Text);
  myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
  displayviewgrid.DataSource = dt;
  wb.Close();
```

I have button in the form through which i can delete the unchecked rows. This buttons does now work properly.For example If there are 10 rows and these all are unchecked and now i press the button  then the all rows should be deleted but it does delete all the rows. it deletes some of them then again i pressed it and then again it deletes rest of them. For checked values it works fine it does not delete them but for more than one unchecked values it is not working properly. It is not deleting them all at once. Here is the code

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow roww in displayviewgrid.Rows)
  {               
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(roww.Cells[Column1.Name].Value) == false)
      {
        displayviewgrid.Rows.Remove(roww);// MessageBox.Show( "sadas"); 
      }              
  }
```

The foreach loop stops automatically after some iterations and it does not run till the last that's why i am unable to delete all the rows. I don't know why it's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace ur remove row code with this code:

```
foreach (var roww in displayviewgrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray())
{               
   if (Convert.ToBoolean(roww.Cells[Column1.Name].Value) == false)
       displayviewgrid.Rows.Remove(roww);// MessageBox.Show( "sadas");               
}
```

Reason: You can not change collection in `foreach` loop, make copy of collection in loop.

More info:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/invalidoperationexception

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @AyyanAlvi Check this one.. Sorry I wasn't test code before.

Comment: Thanks alot brother but can you tell me what was the issue before?

Comment: @AyyanAlvi foreach perform on element which collection has, If u change source collection means foreach contract for collection might get break, so make copy of collection in loop by using ToArray or ToList and then u can change original source collection.